# Can't center a View in an activity in XML (Android)

Tags: android, xml

I have created a new (second) activity in my android app, and right now there is one view in the content_area_reduction.xml (EditText). The file looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.company.myname.appname.AreaReductionActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_area_reduction">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is, the view appears on the left of the screen instead of center. How do I fix this issue? Will post more code if needed.

Thank you

Comment: add android:layout_centerInParent="true" to EditText.

Comment: your code is perfectly fine  i have check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in your `edittext`. You will get `edittext` in center of layout.

**sample code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the line `android:layout_alignParentTop="true`" and add a new one:

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_width="200dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Update EditText Xml

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.company.myname.appname.AreaReductionActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_area_reduction">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit2"
        android:layout_width="200dip"
        android:layout_height="50dip"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit2"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
```